# how to print only english string?

Tags: python, json

I have excel file that contain arabic & english string.

ex:

{"ar": "ابراج التيسير", "en": "abrag altisyr"}

I want to print only english string.

ex:

abrag altisyr

I use this code:

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    hotel_column = (sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
    re = hotel_column.replace('{"ar": "', '')
    res1 = res.replace('", "en": "', ' ')
    res2 = res1.replace('"}', '')
```

but i get :

ابراج التيسير abrag altisyr

Any kind of help please?

Comment: That value is in JSON format, use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and you'll get a dict with `ar` and `en` keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This value is in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format. Use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) and you'll get the dict with those values:

```
import json
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    hotel_column = sheet.cell_value(i, 0)
    data = json.loads(hotel_column)
    print(data['en'])
```